# XMLHttpRequest cannot load an URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, cors

I'm trying to get some json data from a "remote" website.
I run my web service on the 99000 port then, I launch my website on the 99001 port (http://localhost:99001/index.html).

I get the following message:

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:99000/Services.svc/ReturnPersons. Origin http://localhost:99001 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Even If I launch my web page as an HTML file, I get this:

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:99000/Services.svc/ReturnPersons.Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The web service returns data. I try to catch the data items like this:

```
var url = "http://localhost:99000/Services.svc/ReturnPersons";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
success: readData(data)
});
function readData(data) {
    alert(data[0].FirstName);
}
```

And I'm trying to get this structure:

```
[{"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar"},{"Hello":"Foo","LastName":"World"}]
```

Do you know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't do a XMLHttpRequest crossdomain, the only "option" would be a technique called JSONP, which comes down to this:

To start request: Add a new `<script>` tag with the remote url, and then make sure that remote url returns a valid javascript file that calls your callback function. Some services support this (and let you name your callback in a GET parameters).

The other easy way out, would be to create a "proxy" on your local server, which gets the remote request and then just "forwards" it back to your javascript.

**edit/addition:**

I see jQuery has built-in support for JSONP, by checking if the URL contains "callback=?" (where jQuery will replace ? with the actual callback method). But you'd still need to process that on the remote server to generate a valid response.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the "&callback=?" to the URL. Thank you!

Comment: Do I have to specify/implement anything in the server script on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, where your server normally returns a JSON string, e.g. `{"foo": "bar"}` you need to wrap the json string in a callback method (javascript function) that handles the json response. e.g. `myFunction({"foo": "bar"});`

Comment: Charles Leaf, actually you are wrong.  There is another "option" which is called CORS.  Checkout how to enable it here: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: You are right portforwardpodcast, but when this question was originally asked in 2010 CORS was a less popular choice (to be fair: one that I had never heard of back then) and while IE6 support has been dropped by most, there is still a demand to support IE7 which doesn't support CORS and IE8 only supports it partially. So depending on your requirements this is a very valid (and better) option yes.

Answer (score 34):

In new jQuery 1.5 you can use:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:99000/Services.svc/ReturnPersons",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: readData(data),
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
    }
})
```

Comment: i'm, guessing it's extra ":" in your response. could you paste whole message ?

Answer (score 19):

**[Fiddle with 3 working solutions](http://jsfiddle.net/HNPyc/98/)** in action.

**Given an external JSON:**

```
myurl = 'http://wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=frwiki&titles=France&languages=zh-hans|zh-hant|fr&props=sitelinks|labels|aliases|descriptions&format=json'
```

**Solution 1: $.ajax() + jsonp:**

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: myurl ,
  }).done(function ( data ) {
  // do my stuff
});
```

**Solution 2: $.ajax()+json+&calback=?:**

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: myurl + '&callback=?',
  }).done(function ( data ) {
  // do my stuff
});
```

**Solution 3: $.getJSON()+calback=?:**

```
$.getJSON( myurl + '&callback=?', function(data) {
  // do my stuff
});
```

Documentations: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: JSfiddle fixed following #wikidata API changes, jsfiddle improvement done, redaction improvement done !

Comment: @TuhinPaul: when you are on **https** fiddle you cannot request **http** wikidata or others http, it would be a security breach. You can do  http-http, https-https, or http-https, not https-http. This is a security feature, not a cross domain issue.

Answer (score 7):

Found a possible workaround that I don't believe was mentioned.

Here is a good description of the problem:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Basically as long as you use forms/url-encoded/plain text content types you are fine.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost/endpoint",
    data: JSON.stringify({'DataToPost': 123}),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

I use it with ASP.NET WebAPI2. So on the other end:

```
public static void RegisterWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Formatters.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
}
```

This way Json formatter gets used when parsing plain text content type.

And don't forget in Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using WebAPI 3 and was facing the same issue. The issue has resolve as @Rytis added his solution. And I think in WebAPI 3, we don't need to define method `RegisterWebApi`.

My change was only in web.config file and is working.

```
<httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Thanks for you solution @Rytis!