# XMLHttpRequest cannot load Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-post, ajaxform, jquery-ajax

I have a code.html file containing the following code.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    datatype: "JSONP",
    url: "path",
    success: function(msg){
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.id = "ads";
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    $("#ads").html(msg);
    }
});
```

When I open the code.html file in the browser, it gives an error:

```
**"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://..... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."**
```

What is causing this and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is your code.html on the same host (localhost)?

Comment: in same host its works fine. but in different its not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest Origin null is not allowed Access-Control-Access-Allow for file:/// to file:/// (Serverless)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file)

Comment: this is very comprehensive [3 simple solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15747224/1140227)

Answer (score 9):

I will make two assumptions:

- You are probably using chrome
- You are opening a file from the filesystem (i.e. double clicking)

Then, this question is a duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest Origin null is not allowed Access-Control-Allow-Origin for file:/// to file:/// (Serverless)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-access-allow-for-file)

The browser is preventing cross site scripting. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

Answer (score 2):

if you your dataType is `jsonp`(lowercased), the ajax type must be `GET` not `POST`

**Update:**

Use $.getJSON insteadof $.ajax should solve your problem

Comment: what's the address you posted?

Comment: use $.getJSON insteadof $.ajax