# XMLHttpRequest cannot load.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I by `chrome->Inspect element->console` get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

What is this resolved?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy for background. If you are looking for a workaround, you need to add more details about what you are doing.

Comment: The server isn't allowing cross-origin requests. Background info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Comment: [i hope can help you][1]


[click][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230520/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-node


it's idea...

Answer (score 17):

You cannot issue requests through the XMLHttpRequest to other domains or subdomains.
If you are issuing the request from www.foo.com you also need to target the request at www.foo.com and not leave out the www.

If you really need to hit another domain you can use [JsonP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) where the browser utilizes the `<script>` tags ability to load scripts from a different domain. The loaded script then executes a callback function to give you the data. But for regular AJAX calls you cannot leave the source domain at all.

See the Wiki article on [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score 5):

one work around is using [Korz](//github.com/TOMODOcom/TOMODOkorz) which routes all cross origin requests through a third party and sets `Access-Control-Allow-Origin header` to '*' so the request goes through.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to read this:
http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/07/09/how-to-access-cross-domain-data-with-ajax-using-jsonp-jquery-and-php/

It is very wel explained... the whole point is that you need to return your JSON in a callback-function way

Comment: getting a database error on this link, can you please give updated link, if you have one