# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, cors

I have a problem when trying to communicate with my node.js server from ajax requests.

I have configured my server like this :

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,      Accept");
  next();
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

When doing my requests I have this error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.192.122.180:8181/meters. No 'Access-Control-Allow-     Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:6161' is  therefore not allowed access.
```

When I type URL in a browser it works. I have read many things about CORS, same origin policy but now I'm quite lost.

Could someone help me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is correct, but it seems like your code isn't adding it. Check the headers using Firebug or Chrome dev tools on network tab.

Comment: It be good to see the frontend code that was making the request also. I have been battling with similar issues for the past few hours. I had issues with malformed POST data being sent (using jquery). I have the two headers you have there, and also `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');` you can specify multiple rest methods by comma seperated `'POST, GET'` etc. That might help

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem use the following code in server.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're serving the page before your middleware (`allowCrossDomain`) gets a chance to run.

If you're using **Express 3**, try the following:

```
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
app.use(app.router);
```

If you're using **Express 4**, make sure your `app.use(allowCrossDomain)` call is before the rest of your routes (`app.get` and such).

Comment: I have tried but still the same issue. I have a console.log in allowCrossDomain function and in my app.get(...) and only log in allowCrossDomain function is displayed in the console when I try to access to a page. Actually, a friend with its localhost tries to reach my server and we are on the same network. EDIT : I have added the headers in each app.get()method and it works but it doesn't seem the proper way