# jQuery.ajax type: Post to an ashx file not being initiated in IE. works fine in FF, Chrome, and Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, ashx

this is my first question to the stack.

jQuery.ajax type: Post to an ashx file not being initiated in IE. works fine in FF, Chrome, and Safari

Code below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
        url: "http://[ ... ]loguserdata.ashx?" + dataString,
        data: "",
        cache: "false",
        contentType: "text/plain",
        success: function(msg){
            //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
});
```

by works fine in FF, etc. I mean the ashx file is called and info is logged.
I can see the ajax call in fiddler, firebug and chrome's equivalent.

but there doesn't seem to be jackchit happening in IE9 or in IE compatibility mode.

I can get several versions of the code above to work in the other browsers. Including a `$('#result').load( ...`

but NOTHING works in IE

btw, works fine locally in IE.

oh, and I don't give a diddly poo about any return value.

and it's not a cache issue. I have a `date=getTime()` tacked onto the end of the `querystring`.

`querystring (dataString)` looks something like `fname=john&lname=doedy`

**EDIT: I have solved this issue. I will post a thorough answer tomorrow when I have time.**

Comment: check whether you the code is called in your event in IE by putting some alert before ajax call. May be something wrong with some other JQuery

Comment: Consider using an HTTP inspector (e.g. [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)) to look at what's really going back and forth.  Look also for conflicting scripts scrambling things in IE.

Comment: perhaps I should add that creating a direct link via <a href> to the file i.e. href="blah.ashx?fname=john" works fine in all browsers.

Comment: N Rohler nothing is going period.

Comment: Jayantha Alert works fine just before the $.ajax call in all browsers

Comment: Does the ajax call is made in the same domain?

Comment: I have solved this issue. I will post a thorough answer tomorrow when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story truncated:
You can't do a XMLHttpRequest crossdomain. Use jQuery's getJSON method with the querystring parameter &callback=? added to the url. This I believe converts the datatype to JSONP.

```
 var url = 'http://handlers.flowauto.com/eprice/loguserdata.ashx?fname=jim&callback=?';
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            // do some stuff
        });
```

Here are a few links that helped me solve this.

[XMLHttpRequest cannot load an URL with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ see excerpt below

> JSONP If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as
>   defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP
>   instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for
>   more details.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ see excerpt below

> Additional Notes: Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax"
>   requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not
>   successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or
>   protocol. Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin
>   policy restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IE security, since it's work locally. I guess that files on the locahost have more privileges.

Edit:

IE9 prevent doing cross-domain ajax call, Opera browser too.
For IE9 you can read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for a workaround.   It suggest to use XDR (XDomainRequest)  instead of the usual XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: this will be added to a public website. asking users to change their settings really isn't an option.

Comment: I edited my answer according to your comments (not on the same domain)

Answer (score 0):

Try this since you aren't sending POST data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: "http://[ ... ]loguserdata.ashx?" + dataString,        
        cache: "false",
        contentType: "text/plain",
        success: function(msg){
            //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
});
```

Comment: Rick, this still only works in Chrome and FF, but not in IE.

On a side note I just changed from an ashx file to an aspx file.
Same thing. Works in Chrome and FF, but not IE