# XMLHttpRequest cannot load is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, getjson

I'm trying to get access to education.com API data. However, I keep receiving an error the error states:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.education.com/service/service.php?f=schoolSearch&key=mykey&sn=sf&v=4&city=Atlanta&state=ga&Resf=json.
>   Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My code is the following:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://api.education.com/service/service.php?f=schoolSearch&key=mykey&sn=sf&v=4&city=Atlanta&state=ga&Resf=json', 
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Does that api accept a jsonp callback parameter? it doesn't appear to currently. If it doesn't, you can't request it using the browser alone.

Comment: this is very comprehensive [3 simple solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15747224/1140227)

Comment: Try cross-domain ... check http://www.pureexample.com/jquery/cross-domain-ajax.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a browser unless the education.com server is configured to allow CORS (`Cross-Origin Resource Sharing`) requests (That's the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` bit).

Your server could make the request on your behalf, however, and you can then retrieve the data from there.

Answer (score 1):

In ZF1 can be done as below:

```
  public function indexAction() {
    $turnkey = array(
        "uris" => array("176.x.x:3478", "3478"),
        "username" => "my_username",
        "password" => "my_password"
    );

    $content = Zend_Json::encode($turnkey);
    $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->setBody($content)
            ->sendResponse();
    exit;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so much a solution to the problem, but a hack to avoid the problem -- start your browser without web-security:

```
in MacOS this would work as follows: cd to ../../Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS
then start the brwoser with the appropiate flag: Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security'
```

Note: Never use the browser for normal surfing, this is just to get you going in cases of emergencies!
Cheers

Comment: Running `google-chrome --disable-web-security` doesn't solve this problem in Linux. I'd be surprised if this actually works on Mac...