# XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.linkedin.com/.... Origin 'http://xx.xx' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, linkedin-jsapi

I am getting this error when i try to use Linkedin Javascript API to validate user and the trigger a ajax function based on user login status....

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=75--7530050c-c992-4791-95f0-5c43386a147d. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.x.xx' is therefore not allowed access.
```

TEST CASE:

When i click on a button below function call is trigged

```
IN.User.authorize(function(){ call my callback() here if logged-in });
```

The LinkedIn Popup comes and i am able to login to but after that i am getting above error. I am trying the same in my local-machine and hence the website has my ip address.

Anyone help will be highly appreciated as i want to authenticate a user via LinkedIn Javascript API and on success i want to perform a ajax through which i want to send a message to a user.

Comment: AJAX is applied for same domain only.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this.... is there anything i can do to bypass this error? and use the same work flow...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160071/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin