# jQuery fancyBox YouTube videos not working

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, fancybox, xmlhttprequest

I am using WordPress and using jQuery [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) for display YouTube videos but I am getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have added bellow `jQuery code` in footer.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

and added bellow html code inside my post.

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">
    <img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-583" alt="small-screen-youtube" src="http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/small-screen-youtube-150x150.png" width="150" height="150" />
</a>
```

This problem is killing me :(

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Try <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?> in your file

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine http://jsfiddle.net/zMQXt/ but as it was already mentioned, you should test in a server environment. Additionally, in WordPress, you should try using `jQuery` instead of the `$` alias.

Comment: @Manish i have tried this `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` but not working.

Answer (score 9):

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">
<img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-583" alt="small-screen-youtube" src="http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/small-screen-youtube-150x150.png" width="150" height="150" />
</a>
```

All you need to do to fix this is: change 'fancybox.iframe' to 'fancybox iframe' - remove the dot(.), worked for me.

Comment: I can't believe they would do this the wrong way in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The request to the service is failing because of browser [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Your local server is at `http://localhost` while you are trying to access a resource at http://www.youtube.com/. These are both at different domains. So it won't work.

A way to deal with this is to use JSONP or CORS headers (Use the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`), part of the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) spec.

#### Using Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your response.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The above will allow **any** resource to use the service cross-domain. See How to configure `Access-Control-Allow`. [Article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have added this code `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in my header.php in live site but still not working.

Comment: Have a Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery

Comment: Hi Jenson! My problem is solved by using WordPress plugin. `http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/`.

Comment: @Rajnikanth Good. You Can post that as answer how you resolved your problem..That'll help others who experience same kinda issues. Thanks..:)