# d3.js external json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Can someone explain to me why I keep getting this error message:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/iemre/multiday/2013-04-01/2013-04-12/42.54/-96.40/json. Origin ------------ is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

But I can access the data with this URL: http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/iemre/multiday/2013-04-01/2013-04-12/42.54/-96.40/json

```
d3.json("http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/iemre/multiday/2013-04-01/2013-04-12/42.54/-96.40/json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  data = json;
```

Is this not the appropriate way load an external json file using d3?

Comment: what i see you are missing the space after the comma before function

Comment: I think that just happened when I was pasting the code

Comment: This a security measure based on the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load an URL with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery)

Comment: I added &callback=? to the end of the url and am now getting this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" but I am able to see the data in the console.

Answer (score 0):

As @aug posted, this violates the Same Origin Policy. You can read more about it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

The only way that you can get around this issue is if you have control of the JSON file and then you can add "padding" to the file. You can read more about that at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP