# how to fix XMLHttpRequest cannot load "the url target" No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to get some information to my website from an other URL but I have this error when my page tries to load the content.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load "urltarget" No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm using this JavaScript to get the information.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#div").load('urltarget class_contentinfo');
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: um, are those variables that you are treating as a string?

Comment: If you make a new question, and type the exact title of your question (which you just did), you can see a lot of suggestions. This is because this questions has been asked dozens of times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load an URL with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

you can't just load a page from another url that isn't yours.
The problem is, as you already pointed out, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

This means the page you are trying to load data from didn't whitelist your page as a valid source.

Let's consider you are `foo.com` and you want to load data from `bar.com` through a XMLHttpRequest, `bar.com` has to send either `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: foo.com` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

More information on this topic can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing