# Sending parameters to web page using javascript/jQuery without HTML Form Submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two web pages A.html and B.html(Thrid party provided so i dont have access for its code). Where A.html has form and onClick of submit the data is sent to B.html with method="post" and target="chat".

As soon as B.html receives A.html request a pop up for Chat window starts. But now i dont want  the user to fill form every time and submit to start support of chat and i want to accomplish this using javascript/jquery only without asking user to fill in the HTML form.

Below is my form code in html:

```
<label for="sample" style="display: none;">sample</label>
<form name="sample" id="sample" method="post" target="chat" >

    <div class="form_elem">
        Name : <input type="text" id="vName" name="vName" value=""> <div class="error">*</div>

        Mobile Number : <input type="text" id="mobile"  name="21512" value=""> <div class="error">*</div>

        Connection Type : <select name="21524" id="state">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="24">PF</option>
            <option value="25">PD</option>
        </select> <label> &nbsp;</label>

        <input type="button" style="border-width: 0px; margin-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:return Submit_Data();" value="Submit"  name="btnSubmit" class="submit">
        <input type="button" style="border-width: 0px; margin-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:return Clear_Click(&#39;old&#39;)" value="Clear" name="btnclear" class="reset">

    </div>

</form>
```

---

```
function Submit_Data()
{
    window.open("Live Chat", "chat", "height=" + ChatWindow_Height + ", width = " + ChatWindow_Width);

    var url = "B.Html";

    var form = document.getElementById("sample");
    form.action = url;
    form.submit();  
}
```

Assuming data necessary to be sent is hard coded now like. `var name='pawan',mobile='9930667xxx',state='24'`. How to write javascript/jQuery that doesnot involve any html form and submits data directly to B.html ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
            async:true,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            url: "pageB",
            data:"para="+variable,
            beforeSend: function,
            success:function,
            timeout:10000,
            error:function
        });
```

para=variable para is the post in the server $_POST['para']

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I will get back to you soon after trying it.

Comment: I modified your code a bit as like:
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "xyz.com/VisitorChat/B.html",
        data:"vName=pawan&mobile=9930667xxx&state=24",
        success:function(res){ alert("passed "+res); }
    }); 
But in on console i got 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load xyz.com/VisitorChat/B.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxx.21.11.xxx:10080' is therefore not allowed access. index.html:1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery
http://www.coderslexicon.com/tricks-for-getting-around-the-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-security-limitation-in-javascript/

Comment: I don't have any control over that B.Html of different domain site. And yeas its a cross domain call. But one thing i am not getting why submitting via form i am able to work perfectly but not like this.