# XMLHttpRequest error with Google translate (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-domain, google-translate

I am getting this error while trying to access a page that uses Google Translate :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '`http://localhost:8080`' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I have read [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery) about this problem here on SO but I haven't found a way to make it work with the way we initialize the Google Translate gadget.

The solutions that are proposed include setting the `dataType` to `jsonp` and adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the header of the `XMLHttpRequest`. However, I am not doing an AJAX call like the ones in the other posts, only initializing the Google Translate element with a script provided by Google :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',
                    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
                    includedLanguages: 'fr,en'
                }, 'hiddenGoogleTranslate');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

How can I define the `dataType` or add something to the header with this initialization script ? I am new to Javascript so there must be something I am missing out.

Thank you!

Comment: Please consider adding a downvote reason, I know there are lots of posts about this problem but I haven't found any that uses the googleTranslateElementInit script.

Comment: Can u post a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I tried it here http://jsfiddle.net/zznv5tet/ doesn't seem to throw any errors - can u build upon this sample?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Indeed, it works fine in your jsfiddle. The problem happens when we naviguate from one page to another, I don't know how to replicate this in a jsfiddle..!

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use curl or file_get_content() (webproxy) at your server to get translated text. Then you can access that url with ajax. if you want to define "Access control allow origin" header to * you can do it at your server (not from js). your url can be accessed cross domain.