# Access Control Allow Origin - Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a PHP API that verifies the specified credentials. At the beginning of my PHP file I have this

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.org');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Although when I use my API (using AJAX) I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/?params=parameters+go+here. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.org' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**NOTE: I have reason to believe that there is a flaw in the AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.example.com/?type=verify&username=' + username + '&password=' + password,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( result ) {
        success = result['success'];
        return success;
    }
});
```

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
CSF

Comment: clearly your headers are **not** sent - verify in the browser **developer** tools network tab, see what response headers are actually sent

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. Just checked the Developer Network tab I do not know how to see the headers though.

Comment: by clicking on the request (as I don't even know which browser you have, that's the best I can suggest)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. Just checked the headers (using Chrome) All the headers I put in the PHP show up. Any Idea what is going on?

Comment: weird, if chrome says `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` but there **is** a `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` - then chrome is lying to you!!

Comment: Are there any errors in the server, like attempting to set headers after headers have already been sent?

Comment: @JaromandaX Maybe it is not something wrong in the PHP but the AJAX. I will update my question to include the AJAX.

Comment: Is your browser sending a Origin header?

Comment: @juria_roberts How would I find out if it is? If you mean 'Is Chrome saying the header is set?' than yes. But if not I do not understand the question.

Comment: sorry, i just looked at the error message. Looks like the origin is going to the server.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, did not see your post until now. I do not think so since Chrome says they are set. But is there a way to check for header errors??

Comment: I'm not too sure as I don't use PHP much, but I recall that if you enable displaying of errors, the page served by the PHP server will contain the error text.  It should look something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

Comment: Also, another possibility is that the page that is intended to be served by http://example.org is being served by http://localhost, http://127.0.0.1, or as a file:// request, and it doesn't match with the header returned by PHP.  To check this, change your PHP to `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` temporarily and see whether it works.

Comment: @Bernard Ah yes... The headers already sent error. I think my server does send those but I would need to test.

Comment: @Bernard Ok I will try that

Comment: @Bernard that did not work. I tried it but it gave me the same error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it's easy... if you use Chrome i suggest you that install `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` Extension...

[image]

After Added to chrome, you just need to Enable/Disable `cross-origin resource sharing` toggle button...

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: Yes, but what I want is this to be a API accessible for anyone.

Comment: see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers)... Access-Control-Allow-Headers does not allow * as accepted value...
you should send the accepted headers (first X-Requested-With as the error says).

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: Although I did not find an answer there

Comment: see this...(http://stackoverflow.com/a/3829000/5768707)

Questioner asserts that the problem is solved.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for that comment, testing it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to test your code then download the "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" extension Link ~ [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)
but if you want it to work on every browser/client without any requirement of the extension.. then please refer [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) .. GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Is there a version of that using PHP? That would be great thanks.

Comment: refer to this - http://www.mjhall.org/php-cross-origin-resource-sharing/