# Why cant i see my JSON data in my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i write this question because i have this site i need to make, and my only problem is the JSON. 
i have this url with the JSON but when ever i try to work with the link it gives me an error, that you can see further down in my question, but when take all the data from the url i put it in a VAR then i will get no error and i will see me data, but that is not what is supposed to happen.

i got this problem with my JSON, some how i cant see my data on my HTML page, and i cant find the problem.

here you have my HTML page:

```
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3,2,1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <table id="product_table" class="table table-responsive table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Photo</th>
                        <th>Sizes</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Old Price</th>
                        <th>Delivery</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="js/npm.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and here you have my 2 scripts i tried out the first one i try to get the JSON from an url the second one i downloaded the JSON locally down on my pc

```
<!-- <script>
        var productJSON = "https://www.unisport.dk/api/sample/";
            $.getJSON(productJSON, function(data) {
                $.each(data.products, function(i,f){
                    var tblRow ="<tr>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<img class='img-responsive' alt='photo of product' src='" + f.image + "'>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.sizes + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.price + " "  + f.currency + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<s>" + f.price_old + " " + f.currency + "</s>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.delivery + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                     $(tblRow).appendTo("#products tbody");
            });
        });

    </script> -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("unisport.json", function(data){
            var product_data = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                product_data += '<tr>';
                product_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
                product_data += '<td><img scr="'+value.image+'"></td>';
                product_data += '<td>'+value.sizes+'</td>';
                product_data += '<td>'+value.price+' '+value.currency+'</td>';
                product_data += '<td>'+value.price_old+' '+value.currency+'</td>';
                product_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#product_table').append(product_data);
        });
    });    

</script>
```

how the data has been setup:
all the JSON data is from this url: https://www.unisport.dk/api/sample/

```
{"is_customizable": "0", 
"delivery": "1-2 dage", 
"kids": "0", 
"name": "adidas Tr\u00e6ningsbukser Z.N.E. Road Trip - Gr\u00e5", 
"sizes": "XX-Large", 
"kid_adult": "0", 
"free_porto": "0", 
"image": "https://d2ij1pxeion66i.cloudfront.net/product/157128/010c01d20cac.jpg", 
"package": "0", 
"price": "399,00", 
"url": "https://www.unisport.dk/fodboldudstyr/adidas-trningsbukser-zne-road-trip-gra/157128/", 
"online": "1", 
"price_old": "799,00", 
"currency": "DKK", 
"img_url": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/product-img/157128_maxi_0.jpg", 
"id": "157128", 
"women": "0"},
```

This is my error message in my console:[XMLHttpRequest cannot load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgYCp.png)

Now my question is how does i fix the problem if there is one or what does i miss, in order to get it working, also i would really like to get the Data trough the URL as shown in the first script

(also i only use jQuery, Bootstrap and HTML in this project.)

**EDIT**
*Problem fixed, since i'm doing this project locally on my PC i had to start up a local server, that i forgot all about.
So if any one else have some problems as me **BE SURE TO DOUBLE CHECK** that you have a local server running for the project*

Comment: Please include JS code used.

Comment: `and here you have my 2 scripts i tried out` - look again, there's nothing "here" - before you do anything, have you checked the browsers **developer** tools console for errors? (F12 to bring it up)

Comment: @JaromandaX sry about that somehow it posted it before i was done making the post, but i forgot all about looking for errors in my console, but i can see i get an "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" error

Comment: Thus there is a problem with your  `$.getJSON("unisport.json", ...);` call. You are not getting a JSON response. The rest of your code looks fine, make sure the json path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kXdAYeRwLTtZeP42wcbd?p=preview)

```js
 var unisport = [{
"is_customizable": "0", 
"delivery": "1-2 dage", 
"kids": "0", 
"name": "adidas Tr\u00e6ningsbukser Z.N.E. Road Trip - Gr\u00e5", 
"sizes": "XX-Large", 
"kid_adult": "0", 
"free_porto": "0", 
"image": "https://d2ij1pxeion66i.cloudfront.net/product/157128/010c01d20cac.jpg", 
"package": "0", 
"price": "399,00", 
"url": "https://www.unisport.dk/fodboldudstyr/adidas-trningsbukser-zne-road-trip-gra/157128/", 
"online": "1", 
"price_old": "799,00", 
"currency": "DKK", 
"img_url": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/product-img/157128_maxi_0.jpg", 
"id": "157128", 
"women": "0"
},
{
"is_customizable": "0", 
"delivery": "1-2 dage", 
"kids": "0", 
"name": "adidas Tr\u00e6ningsbukser Z.N.E. Road Trip - Gr\u00e5", 
"sizes": "XX-Large", 
"kid_adult": "0", 
"free_porto": "0", 
"image": "https://d2ij1pxeion66i.cloudfront.net/product/157128/010c01d20cac.jpg", 
"package": "0", 
"price": "399,00", 
"url": "https://www.unisport.dk/fodboldudstyr/adidas-trningsbukser-zne-road-trip-gra/157128/", 
"online": "1", 
"price_old": "799,00", 
"currency": "DKK", 
"img_url": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/product-img/157128_maxi_0.jpg", 
"id": "157128", 
"women": "0"
},
{
"is_customizable": "0", 
"delivery": "1-2 dage", 
"kids": "0", 
"name": "adidas Tr\u00e6ningsbukser Z.N.E. Road Trip - Gr\u00e5", 
"sizes": "XX-Large", 
"kid_adult": "0", 
"free_porto": "0", 
"image": "https://d2ij1pxeion66i.cloudfront.net/product/157128/010c01d20cac.jpg", 
"package": "0", 
"price": "399,00", 
"url": "https://www.unisport.dk/fodboldudstyr/adidas-trningsbukser-zne-road-trip-gra/157128/", 
"online": "1", 
"price_old": "799,00", 
"currency": "DKK", 
"img_url": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/product-img/157128_maxi_0.jpg", 
"id": "157128", 
"women": "0"
}]
 
 

var product_data = '';
$.each(unisport, function(key, value){
                product_data += '<tr>';
                product_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
                product_data += '<td><img style="height:50px;width:50px;" src="'+value.image+'"></td>';
                product_data += '<td>'+value.sizes+'</td>';
                product_data += '<td>'+value.price+' '+value.currency+'</td>';
                product_data += '<td>'+value.price_old+' '+value.currency+'</td>';
                product_data += '<td>'+value.delivery+'</td>';
                product_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#product_table').append(product_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container-fluid">
            <table id="product_table" class="table table-responsive table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Photo</th>
                        <th>Sizes</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Old Price</th>
                        <th>Delivery</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
```

Comment: Hello.
I have tried to use plunker and done it the same way as you, tried both with the VAR to store my data, and from my json file, i also tried to get the data through an URL but, when i load op the side on my PC it wont load the data (i get anXMLHttpRequest cant load error) but when i do i on plunker i get no error and my data get putted in the table as i want, but how can it work on plunker but not on my pc?

Comment: May it help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help, i found out that i forgot to start a local server.
also thanks for the site, i did not know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems fine. By process of elimination, there must be a problem with the `$.getJSON("unisport.json", function(data) { ... } );` call. You must either not be getting a JSON response from the server or the JSON in the expected format.

Either attempt to `console.log` the received JSON response to affirm it is in the expected format or check your debugger to see if `$.getJSON` has thrown an error.

Comment: Hello i get no error when i try to debug my site, and when i look in my console i get the XMLHttpRequest cannot load error, its like it can "find" the data/json but i dont have access to it?

Comment: The problem is fixed, i forgot to start my local server :D